# Git merging independent files to different branches

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

i would like to know if i can merge my local branch changes to different branches .Lets suppose i have two remote branches name "Live" to which i commit only after testing is done from a branch called "test".
So on every new fix or a functionality i create a local branch and checkout from "test" and i merge my changes to it and push it to origin by these commands,

```
git checkout test
git merge 'local-branch'
git push origin.
```

How would i merge my local files to "live" also  without need to checkout a local branch from "live".

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Jack thanks for the answer, "test" is the dedicated remote branch for all the bug fixes so  i need to push my files into it .But after i get confirmation to make it live ,that means fix has been verified by the team i need to push it to "live" remote branch .

Comment: It gets complicated when your test branch is created from the live branch, because then you'd always have to cherry-pick if there are multiple things to test.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe git pull, for merge to master branch

```
      A---B---C origin/master
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a different approach, without the need for a test branch.

Create your feature branch from the live branch as per normal:

```
o---o        live branch
    |
    o----o   feature branch
```

Then, run the tests **on the feature branch directly** (or after pushing it to the origin). Once it passes, you can merge the changes into the live branch with a simple three-way merge.

In fact, systems like Github and Bitbucket provide this using pull requests.